# Keras model building

Tags: python, keras

I am coming from tensorflow learning more about keras and came across this notation. I looked in the documentation but couldn't find any examples. The syntax is when a function is followed with a variable in parenthesis.

```
model_input = Input(shape=input_shape)

z = model_input
z = Dropout(dropout_prob[0])(z) # Not sure what this means
```

The only idea I had is this may be  a layer multiplication, but I am not sure thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's part of the Sequential model in Keras; as it's stated in the doc [here](https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/)

- A layer instance is callable (on a tensor), and it returns a tensor
- Input tensor(s) and output tensor(s) can then be used to define a
  Model
- Such a model can be trained just like Keras Sequential models.

So following up your code (that is only a portion), first probably you imported

```
from keras.layers import Input, Dropout
```

Then in var "model_input" you return a tensor

```
model_input = Input(shape=input_shape)
```

And then a layer instance is callable on a tensor, and returns a tensor

```
z = model_input
z = Dropout(dropout_prob[0])(z) # This returns another tensor
```

After that, for example, you can follow with a model like this:

```
from keras.models import Model

model = Model(inputs=model_input, outputs=z)
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',
              loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(data, labels)  # starts training
```

So now, it is easy to reuse trained models: you can treat any model as if it were a layer, by calling it on a tensor, like this:

```
x = Input(shape=(784,))
y = model(x)
```

Comment: thank you for your great response, I didn't get that last part of reusing trained models. Is that line of code just using the trained model with a new input shape?